# Statement outside of loop gets repeated c++

Tags: c++, iostream, cin, getline

I try to read tokens from the input of a user like a compiler.
The tokenization works fine but when outputting all the tokens i want to make a newline after they are all given out.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
//import for using std::getline()
#include <string>

//DIGITs
const std::string DIGITS = "0123456789";
const std::string WHITESPACE = " \t\n\r";

//TOKENS
const std::string TT_INT = "INT";
const std::string TT_FLOAT = "FLOAT";
const std::string TT_PLUS = "PLUS";
const std::string TT_MINUS = "MINUS";
const std::string TT_MUL = "MUL";
const std::string TT_DIV = "DIV";
const std::string TT_LPAREN = "LPAREN";
const std::string TT_RPAREN = "RPAREN";

const std::string TT_INVALID_NUMBER = "INVALID_NUMBER_LITERAL";

class Token{
    public: 
        std::string type;
        std::string value;
    
    void repr(){
        std::cout << type << ":" << "value" << "\n";
    }
};

class Lexer{
    public:
        std::string text;
        int position = -1;
        std::string current_char;
    
    void advance(){
        this->position += 1;
        this->current_char = this->text[this->position];
    }

    void make_digit(std::string *type, std::string *value){
        //if its number or floating point
        std::string digit = "";
        int is_float = 0;
        while(DIGITS.find(this->current_char) != std::string::npos || this->current_char == "."){
            digit += this->current_char;
            if(this->current_char == "."){
                is_float += 1;
            }
            this->advance();
        }
        *value = digit;
        if(is_float == 0){
            *type = TT_INT;
        } else if((0 < is_float) && (is_float < 2)){
            *type = TT_FLOAT;
        } else {
            *type = TT_INVALID_NUMBER;
        }
    }    

    std::vector<std::string> make_tokens(){
        std::vector<std::string> tokens;
        this->advance();

        while (!(this->text.length() <= this->position))
        {
            if(WHITESPACE.find(this->current_char) != std::string::npos){
                //dont add a token
                this->advance();
            } else if(DIGITS.find(this->current_char) != std::string::npos){
                std::string type;
                std::string value;
                this->make_digit(&type, &value);
                tokens.push_back(type);
                tokens.push_back(value);
            } else if(this->current_char == "+"){
                tokens.push_back(TT_PLUS);
                tokens.push_back(this->current_char);
                this->advance();
            } else if(this->current_char == "-"){
                tokens.push_back(TT_MINUS);
                tokens.push_back(this->current_char);
                this->advance();
            } else if(this->current_char == "*"){
                tokens.push_back(TT_MUL);
                tokens.push_back(this->current_char);
                this->advance();
            } else if(this->current_char == "/"){
                tokens.push_back(TT_DIV);
                tokens.push_back(this->current_char);
                this->advance();
            } else if(this->current_char == "("){
                tokens.push_back(TT_LPAREN);
                tokens.push_back(this->current_char);
                this->advance();
            } else if(this->current_char == ")"){
                tokens.push_back(TT_RPAREN);
                tokens.push_back(this->current_char);
                this->advance();
            } else {
                //nothing
                this->advance();
            }
        }             
        return tokens;  
    }

};

int main(){
    //previous: true
    while(std::getline(std::cin, input)){
        std::string input;
        //previous: std::cin >> input;
        //fix
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        Lexer mylexer;
        mylexer.text = input;
        int x = 0;
        std::vector<std::string> output = mylexer.make_tokens();
        for (int i = 0; i < output.size(); i += 2){
            std::cout << output.at(i) << ":" << output.at(i + 1) << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
};
```

When entering 1 + 2

What i expected

```
1 + 2
INT:1
PLUS:+
INT:2

here is the cursor
```

What i got

```
1 + 2
INT:1

PLUS:+

INT:2

here is the cursor
```

When removing the newline at the end i get this, but when entering a second input line it is all together without empty lines, which is not what i want

```
1 + 2
INT:1
PLUS:+
INT:2
here is the cursor
```

But i want it to look like this

```
1 + 2
INT:1
PLUS:+
INT:2

3 + 4
INT:3
PLUS:+
INT:4
```

Can anyone explain what this strange behaviour is?
Am I missing something? Note that i don't have much C++ experience.
I'm on windows compiling with clang-cl.exe. And im also wondering what the throw_bad_array_new_lengthv error means when compiling with MSYS2 g++.exe

Comment: Suggestion: if you have a problem with a loop, remove everything but the loop from the program. Once all of the noise is gone the source of the problem is often obvious. Use [mre] for inspiration.

Comment: You are outputing two new lines.  First you dump `std::endl` which puts a new line.  Then you output `\n` which outputs another.  Get rid of the `\n`

Comment: @joe but what i dont understand is why it even gets repeated 3 times, because i suppose it is not in the loop. also see my edit

Comment: When I run the code shown as-is, I get a runtime error. So there is a bug in the logic somewhere.

Comment: @RemyLebeau which error message? Edit: is it because of compiling with g++?

Comment: @Redstonerayy It is because of the `while(true)` loop never terminating, so it crashes after while when there is no more input to read.  You need to fix the `while` loop to end when there is no more input available to read. I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the extra line breaks in your output is because you are using `operator>>` to read in the `input`.

`operator>>` only reads in 1 word at a time.  It stops reading when whitespace is encountered.

So, when you enter `1 + 2` as your input, you end up calling `make_tokens()` with only the first word `1` as the `mylexer.text`, then your loop prints out `INT:1` followed by a line break, and then you print out another line break after the loop exits.  Then, you read in the next word `+`, tokenize it, and print out `PLUS:+` followed by 2 line breaks.  Then you read in the next word `2`, tokenize it, and print out `INT:2` followed by 2 line breaks.

Use `std::getline(std::cin, input);` instead.  Then you will tokenize the entire input `1 + 2` in one call to `make_tokens()`, and then you will print out the kind of output you are expecting - all 3 tokens, with 1 line break between them, and then 1 more line break after the end.

---

On a side note: you should not be using a `while(true)` loop, especially since you are ignoring whether or not `std::cin` is even successful in reading.  You are causing an endless loop that can crash the code.

You should use `std::cin`'s error state to stop the loop when there is no more input to read, eg:

```cpp
std::string input;
while (std::cin >> input){
    // use input as needed...
}
```

Or, in the case of `std::getline()`:

```cpp
std::string input;
while (std::getline(std::cin, input)){
    // use input as needed...
}
```

Comment: this solved it. to my understanding. is it std::cin something like a queque of words so everytime i call it the 1. word in queque will be set into the variable and therefore the for loop will always only be executed once and the while loop 3 times?

Comment: No, `std::cin` is not a queue of words. But that is how your code is treating `std::cin`. The behavior is due to how `operator>>` reads data from *any* `istream`, the behavior is not in `std::cin` itself. That is why `std::getline()` fixes the issue, since it won't stop reading until a line break or EOF is reached from `std::cin`. Different ways of reading from the same stream.

Comment: so the iostream library(now the name makes sense) handles this console input somehow and std::cin and std::getline() are only functions to access it.

Comment: It is a bit more complicated than that. `std::cin` is just a standard `std::istream` object, nothing special about it. `operator>>` and `std::getline()` can read from *any* `std::istream` object (others include `std::ifstream`, `std::istringstream`, etc). An `std::istream` object has an associated `std::stream_buf` object that it reads from. And by default, `std::cin` is assigned a `std::stream_buf` that knows how to read from the console's `STDIN` input. So `operator>>/getline <- cin <- stream_buf <- STDIN`.  Similar for `std::cout` w/ `STDOUT`, and `std::cerr` w/ `STDERR`.