# Visual Studio Code doesn't identify std library when it compiles "_zst28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, mingw, settings

So basically I was following [the official documentation of setting up C++ with Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp). So I followed every step and copied their code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg{"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string &word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

**EDIT** When I compile the code an .exe file is generated correctly. However, when I try to run the compile programme [I get the following mistake as popup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LivpF.png). When I try to run it from my VSCode terminal I don't get that mistake "_zst28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv", [it just gets executed without doing anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK5zY.png)
This is my task.json configuration. I am not sure where I made a mistake while setting up. The code compiles, but it does not run.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe compilar archivo activo",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compilador: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for participating in SO.

It is unclear to me what "However, I get the following mistake" means. Is this a compiler error or an error of VSCode?

Please, be more clear, in particular by providing command line inputs and outputs.

Comment: I added a new edit. It is honestly so confusing why after my code gets compiled, when I try to run the compiled file it just does not work, cause I get that popup mistake that I showed. I am not sure if it has something to do with the configuration, cause it seems like the std library is not found, and therefore generates that error

Comment: I searched for throw_bad_array_new_lengthv and found this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70010869/statement-outside-of-loop-gets-repeated-c. May be it is somehow related. I don't have enough information about your setup to reproduce. Would you mind to publish your project folder in GitHub. Then I would try to help you.